# Install R serve on RHEL 7.5

Tags: r, rhel7

Installed R 3.4.1 in RHEL 7.5(maipo) by using the below commands

```
wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.4.1.tar.gz
tar xvzf R-3.4.1.tar.gz
cd R-3.4.1
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum install ncurses-devel zlib-devel texinfo gtk+-devel gtk2-devel qt-devel tcl-devel tk-devel kernel-headers kernel-devel readline-devel
yum install bzip2-devel
yum install xz xz-devel
yum -y install libcurl libcurl-devel
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
yum install gsl-devel
yum install openssl-devel
yum install libcurl-devel
yum install pulseaudio-libs-devel
yum install python-devel
yum install glibc-static
yum install glibc-devel
yum install libbz2-dev
yum install zlib-devel glibc
./configure --enable-R-shlib --with-readline=no --with-x=no
make
make install
```

Then i tried to install Rserve 
by install.packages("Rserve")
It reports as below

```
sha1.o standalone.o tls.o ulog.o utils.o websockets.o winembed.o -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lcrypt -L/usr/local/lib64/R/lib -lR
/bin/ld: cannot find -lR
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Rserve.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rserve’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib64/R/library/Rserve’
```

Can any one help me on this ?

Comment: What is the content of `/usr/local/lib64/R/lib`?

Comment: It has `libRblas.so` and `libRlapack.so`

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but to long for a comment:

I have tried to reproduce this using this Docker file:

```
FROM centos:7.5.1804

RUN yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools" \
 && yum -y install ncurses-devel zlib-devel texinfo gtk+-devel gtk2-devel qt-devel \
                   tcl-devel tk-devel readline-devel bzip2-devel xz xz-devel \
                   libcurl libcurl-devel java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel gsl-devel \
                   openssl-devel libcurl-devel pulseaudio-libs-devel python-devel \
                   glibc-static glibc-devel libbz2-dev zlib-devel glibc

RUN yum -y install wget \
 && wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.4.1.tar.gz \
 && tar xvzf R-3.4.1.tar.gz \
 && cd R-3.4.1 \
 && ./configure --enable-R-shlib --with-readline=no --with-x=no \
 && make \
 && make install

RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("Rserve", repo="https://cloud.r-project.org/")'
```

However, for me `libR` is created and and the Docker image is build without problem:

```
$ docker run --rm centos-r ls /usr/local/lib64/R/lib
libR.so
libRblas.so
libRlapack.so
```

Some further ideas:

- Are you sure you used a freshly unpacked source directory?
- Can't you simply use the R packages provided by EPEL?
- Follow the installation instructions from [RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218004217-Building-R-from-source):

  - enable EPEL
  - `yum-builddep R`
  - `./configure --enable-R-shlib ...`